# CSS menu align left in IE7 - how to center menu in all browsers (IE7, IE8, firefox, ect)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm having trouble with this menu:   http://www.krillhome.com/home1.html

The problem is that in IE 7 the css menu aligns to the left, where I need it centered. When I add `align="center"` to the div, this corrects the problem in IE7, however this then pushes the entire menu to the right approx 20 pixels in every other browser.

I thought maybe my margins were off, but they look ok. I was hoping I could add `<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <div class="nav-wrap" align="center"> <![endif]-->` but that doesn't work either.

This is how it looks in IE7: http://www.krillhome.com/incorrect.png (note the menu aligned left)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed is that your menu is not actually centered, it just has some left padding (inherited from the default browser styles most likely). The `ul` has not had it's padding removed. Try adding these styles:

```
.nav-wrap { text-align:center }
.nav-wrap ul { padding:0 }
```

Give that a try and see if it centers your menu. It works in Firefox for me. You might rather use `display:block;margin:0 auto;width:***px` instead.

Some "by-the-way" comments:

Since you already have the IE conditionals adding classes to the `<html>` tag for different versions of IE, you can target those browsers like so:

```
html.ie7 {/* some rule for IE7 */}
```

I see you have the HTML5 doctype, but you have a lot of "old-school" (aka deprecated) HTML attributes. `align` is not valid and has not been for a while. I would highly suggest removing those completely and sticking to just CSS.

There are some javascript parse errors there as well. You should get aquianted with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Also have a look at a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

Comment: great, thanks, i used a css reset and that worked.. thanks so much (ps im cleaning out my obsolete code)

Answer (score 0):

Applying `text-align:center` to the UL will center-align it in IE7. It doesn't seem to affect that small green bar (which remains aligned to the left), but the list items themselves are centered.

EDIT: You can use conditional comments to apply this CSS only in Internet Explorer 7:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." type="text/css"> <![endif]-->
```